# Git switch branch without losing changes

Tags: git

I'm working on a project using Git for versioning. I'm now working on a feature in a different branch. I have not completed my changes but I need to switch to a different branch from master branch. I have tried to stash my changes with

```
git stash
```

But it's not stashing my changes.

I checked with

```
git stash list 
git status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have untracked files.
By default, git stash the uncommitted changes(staged and un-staged files) and overlooks untracked and ignored files. you can add them for tracking,

```
git add .
```

or you can force stash or include untracked files like below,

```
git stash -u
git stash --include-untracked
```

if it doesn't help please show the output of "git status" command.

Comment: to unstash chnage I can run, git stash apply?

Comment: yes, apply will apply the stash. But it will not remove the stash. So if you will not need the stash again use "git stash pop"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for fast branch switching could be to use a tool that automates git for you.

One of those is for instance [HighFlux](https://www.highflux.io/) which manages your branch for you and makes switching instant without having to stash.

Another option is [Gitless](https://github.com/gitless-vcs/gitless) which also keeps track of your working changes together with the branch so that switching doesn't require stash.